# nvidia deepstream on v4l2src(c application)

Tags: gstreamer, nvidia

I am having hard time converting my pipeline to an application. I am a newbie so please bear with me on this. I have my pipeline like this,

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! capsfilter caps= 'video/x-raw,format=(string)YUY2' ! nvvidconv ! capsfilter caps= 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=(string)NV12' ! nvvidconv ! capsfilter caps= 'video/x-raw,format=(string)NV12' ! nvvideoconvert ! capsfilter caps='video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=(string)NV12' ! mux.sink_0 nvstreammux live-source=1 name=mux batch-size=1 width=1280 height=720 ! nvinfer config-file-path=/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-4.0/sources/apps/sample_apps/deepstream-test1/dstest1_pgie_config.txt batch-size=1 ! nvmultistreamtiler rows=1 columns=1 width=1280 height=720 ! nvvideoconvert ! nvdsosd ! nvegltransform ! nveglglessink
```

I am trying to get the video source directly from the camera source that I attached to nvidia directly. And I wrote a c-application as below for the above pipeline.

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "gstnvdsmeta.h"


#define MAX_DISPLAY_LEN 64

#define PGIE_CLASS_ID_VEHICLE 0
#define PGIE_CLASS_ID_PERSON 2

gint frame_number = 0;
gchar pgie_classes_str[4][32] = { "Vehicle", "TwoWheeler", "Person",
"Roadsign"
};


static GstPadProbeReturn osd_sink_pad_buffer_probe(GstPad *pad, GstPadProbeInfo *info, gpointer u_data)
{
GstBuffer *buf=(GstBuffer *)info->data;
guint num_rects =0;
NvDsObjectMeta *obj_meta = NULL;
guint vehicle_count = 0;
guint person_count = 0;
NvDsMetaList * l_frame = NULL;
NvDsMetaList * l_obj = NULL;
NvDsDisplayMeta *display_meta = NULL;

NvDsBatchMeta *batch_meta = gst_buffer_get_nvds_batch_meta (buf);

for (l_frame = batch_meta->frame_meta_list; l_frame != NULL;
l_frame = l_frame->next) {
NvDsFrameMeta *frame_meta = (NvDsFrameMeta *) (l_frame->data);
int offset = 0;
for (l_obj = frame_meta->obj_meta_list; l_obj != NULL;
l_obj = l_obj->next) {
obj_meta = (NvDsObjectMeta *) (l_obj->data);
if (obj_meta->class_id == PGIE_CLASS_ID_VEHICLE) {
vehicle_count++;
num_rects++;
}
if (obj_meta->class_id == PGIE_CLASS_ID_PERSON) {
person_count++;
num_rects++;
}
}
display_meta = nvds_acquire_display_meta_from_pool(batch_meta);
NvOSD_TextParams *txt_params = &display_meta->text_params[0];
display_meta->num_labels = 1;
txt_params->display_text = g_malloc0 (MAX_DISPLAY_LEN);
offset = snprintf(txt_params->display_text, MAX_DISPLAY_LEN, "Person = %d ", person_count);
offset = snprintf(txt_params->display_text + offset , MAX_DISPLAY_LEN, "Vehicle = %d ", vehicle_count);

/* Now set the offsets where the string should appear */
txt_params->x_offset = 10;
txt_params->y_offset = 12;

/* Font , font-color and font-size */
txt_params->font_params.font_name = "Serif";
txt_params->font_params.font_size = 10;
txt_params->font_params.font_color.red = 1.0;
txt_params->font_params.font_color.green = 1.0;
txt_params->font_params.font_color.blue = 1.0;
txt_params->font_params.font_color.alpha = 1.0;

/* Text background color */
txt_params->set_bg_clr = 1;
txt_params->text_bg_clr.red = 0.0;
txt_params->text_bg_clr.green = 0.0;
txt_params->text_bg_clr.blue = 0.0;
txt_params->text_bg_clr.alpha = 1.0;

nvds_add_display_meta_to_frame(frame_meta, display_meta);
}

g_print ("Frame Number = %d Number of objects = %d "
"Vehicle Count = %d Person Count = %d\n",
frame_number, num_rects, vehicle_count, person_count);
frame_number++;
return GST_PAD_PROBE_OK;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
GstElement *pipeline, *source, *filter1, *convert,*filter2, *filter3, *vidconv, *filter4, *mux, *infer, *tiler, *osd, *transform , *sink, *bin, *convert2 , *vidconv2;
GMainLoop *loop;
GstCaps *caps1, *caps2, *caps3, *caps4;
GstPad *osd_sink_pad =NULL, *srcpad, *sinkpad;


loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL,FALSE);
gst_init(&argc, &argv);
pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("nv_pipeline");
gchar *string1 = "video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=(string)NV12";

source = gst_element_factory_make("v4l2src", "source");
filter1 = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "filter1");
convert = gst_element_factory_make("nvvidconv", "convert");
filter2 = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "filter2");
filter3 = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "filter3");
filter4 = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "filter4");
vidconv = gst_element_factory_make("nvvideoconvert", "vidconv");
mux = gst_element_factory_make("nvstreammux", "mux");
infer = gst_element_factory_make("nvinfer", "infer");
tiler = gst_element_factory_make("nvmultistreamtiler", "tiler");
osd = gst_element_factory_make("nvosd", "osd");
transform = gst_element_factory_make("nvegltransform", "transform");
sink = gst_element_factory_make("nveglglessink", "sink");
convert2 = gst_element_factory_make("nvvidconv", "convert2");
vidconv2 = gst_element_factory_make("nvvideoconvert", "vidconv2");

gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), source,filter1,convert,filter2, convert2,filter3,vidconv, filter4,mux,infer, tiler,vidconv2, osd,transform,sink,NULL);

gst_element_link_many(source,filter1,convert,filter2, convert2,filter3, vidconv, filter4,mux,infer, tiler,vidconv2, osd,transform,sink,NULL);

osd_sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(osd, "sink");
gst_pad_add_probe(osd_sink_pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER, osd_sink_pad_buffer_probe, NULL, NULL);

caps1 = gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-raw", "format",G_TYPE_STRING,"YUY2",NULL);
caps2 = gst_caps_from_string(string1);
caps3 = gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-raw", "format", G_TYPE_STRING,"NV12", NULL);
caps4 = gst_caps_from_string(string1);

g_object_set(G_OBJECT(filter1), "caps", caps1, NULL);
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(filter2), "caps", caps2, NULL);
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(filter3), "caps", caps3, NULL);
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(filter4), "caps", caps4, NULL);

g_object_set(G_OBJECT(mux), "live-source", 1, "name", "mux", "batch-size", 1, "width", 1280, "height", 720, NULL);
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(infer), "config-file-path","/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-4.0/sources/apps/sample_apps/deepstream-test1/dstest1_pgie_config.txt",NULL);
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(infer), "batch-size", 1, NULL);
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(tiler), "rows", 1, "columns", 1, "width", 1280, "height", 720, NULL);

gst_caps_unref(caps1);
gst_caps_unref(caps2);
gst_caps_unref(caps3);
gst_caps_unref(caps4);

gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
g_print("Running ...\n");
g_main_loop_run(loop);

gst_element_set_state(pipeline,GST_STATE_NULL);
gst_object_unref(pipeline);
return 0;
}
```

I am not sure where I should apply pads, and bins in my current pipeline and when I run this pipeline in command line, it works. But when I try to run using the c program above, it runs and doesn't display anything. Please help. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Without checking your code - have you considered `gst_parse_launch()` to create your pipeline? That is a great starting point to create a pipeline with the same string you use with the `gst-launch-1.0` application.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch good point. I tried running my pipeline with gst_parse_launch() after you suggested and somehow it is trying to create engine from model files but displaying nothing. The same with my above code. Why is it that when I run the same pipeline as command line, it runs,but when I try to run the same pipeline using c application, it doesn't? Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Perhaps your working directory is different? Without errors hard to say. But if it gives you errors you will have to track them down and fix them..

Comment: @FlorianZwoch that is the problem. It is not throwing any errors, it just doesnt display anything. But the good thing is. from GST_LOG I can see that that model files are being loaded and all. It just outputs the exact same lines(except for memory locations) that it does in my working command line pipeline. It just doesn't display anything like a window or anything.